# Plotly: Surface not showing in 3D plot

Tags: r, 3d, plotly

When using the below code in R, my 3D scatterplot shows up fine with the appropriate titled, but the trace doesn't show at all. Does anyone know how to make the trace show up?

```
    graph_reso <- 5

    #Setup Axis
    axis_x <- seq(min(temp$VarA), max(temp$VarA), by = graph_reso)
    axis_z <- seq(min(temp$VarB), max(temp$VarB), by = graph_reso)
    lm_surface <- expand.grid(VarA = axis_x,VarB = axis_z,KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = F)
    lm_surface$VarC <- predict.lm(regr, newdata = lm_surface)
    lm_surface <- acast(lm_surface, VarB ~ VarA, value.var = "VarC") #y ~ x

    if (i == "ALL") {
            fig <- plot_ly(temp, x = ~VarA, y = ~VarC, z = ~VarB,color = ~pop, colors=colorVec,
            hoverinfo = 'text',
            text = ~paste0(names2,"<br>VarA: ",VarA2,"<br>VarB: ",VarB2,"<br>VarC: ",VarC2))
    } else {
            fig <- plot_ly(temp, x = ~VarA, y = ~VarC, z = ~VarB, hoverinfo = 'text',
            text = ~paste0(names2,"<br>VarA: ",VarA2,"<br>VarB: ",VarB2,"<br>VarC: ",VarC2))
    }
    fig <- fig %>% add_markers()
    fig <- fig %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'VarA'),
                 yaxis = list(title = 'VarC'),
                 zaxis = list(title = 'VarB')))

    fig <- add_trace(p = fig,
                 z = axis_z,
                 x = axis_x,
                 y = lm_surface,
                 type = "surface",showscale = FALSE)

    dir.create(paste0(outDir,"Title",i),recursive=T,showWarnings=F)
    htmlwidgets::saveWidget(
            widget = fig, #the plotly object
            file = paste0(outDir,"Title",i,"/Title",i,"_3D.html"), #the path & file name
            selfcontained = F #creates a single html file
            )
```

I wrote the scatterplot to a html file and could not see the trace. The legend showed up when showscale was TRUE, and when viewing the lm_surface variable, the points seemed like they should show up. I also tried add trace both with and without `fig %>%` before it.